# Can the fabricate spell create beer?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, food-and-drink

Given the raw ingredients, can the [*fabricate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate) spell create beer if the caster is proficient with and has Brewer's supplies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, if you have alcohol, water, CO2 and some kind of grain, and proficiency in Brewer's supplies

By obtaining something alcoholic (fermented fruit, perhaps), water, grain for taste only and Carbon Dioxide (hopefully in rich supply) then you can combine these ingredients into a convincing replica of alcohol.

Those raw ingredients form the vast majority of the end product of beer and could be arranged into that form via [Fabricate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate). For more in depth imitation of flavour, you may need to have on hand sugars, yeast, or other beer brewing byproducts to mix in in small amounts.

Comment: I admire your point, but it answers a somewhat different question than the OP.  You are answering the question: "Is there anyway I can make beer, or a replica of it, with Fabricate?" But the question was about using the raw ingredients of *beer* to make, literally, beer.  Therefore I think your answer would be 100% accurate if you changed the "Yes" in your headline to "No, but".

Comment: @ValleyLad I would argue differently; I do answer the question of fabricate making beer from raw ingredients, however the "Raw Ingredients" are a little different than those used in the traditional manner.

Comment: Not sure the OP's intent there.  But putting that aside for sake of argument, to make it taste like beer you still need yeast: it contributes flavor, not just alcohol production. https://drinks.seriouseats.com/2013/01/how-to-indentify-yeast-character-in-beer-what-are-esters-phenols-alcohol.html

Comment: @ValleyLad so he can use dead yeast. You can use dead creatures as materials (lumber for bridges, flax for cloth).

Comment: Contemporary efforts are underway to create (relatively) instant whiskey by bypassing (much of) the process.  http://whiskyadvocate.com/rapid-aging-whiskey-feature/  No mention of "magic", but the article does include "topped with dragon heads" as an interesting coincidence.

Comment: @MilesBedinger normal plants are not creatures.

Comment: Sugar is not a needed as a ingredient for beer. Neither is CO2. In Germany, for example, the law mandated that the *only* ingredients for beer can be water, hops, malt and yeast, and they produce beer just fine. In many beers, the yeast is later filtered out.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes and no.

Fabricate is not replacing the brewing process, it's more of a magical mixer, putting materials in place. If you put beer in a centrifuge to separate out its building blocks, you would use those.

You can't fabricate alcohol out of water and hops, but you could provide grain alcohol as a material. Using fabricate to clear out impurities and add the raw alcohol to hops and yeast, you could create a rough beer.

I imagine your character would need a lot of practice with the fabricate to make a *decent* beer, but proficiency in brewing supplies could make something that passes for beer.

Comment: If I am reading this awnser correctly, it may be more clear to say that one could distill or modify alcohol using fabricate.   I.E. turn a large quantity of beer into barely wine (which is a high percentage alcohol beer) or re-flavor the alcohol in question.   It might be useful to mention given beer, wood and iron, one could make the trade goods "Barrel of Beer" from the PHB.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes if your DM decrees liquid can be an object

Most of the other answers are focused on the raw materials. I think these are the easy part: if you have access to hops, yeast<sup>1</sup>, water and grain, you could manufacture beer from it. They are all the raw materials<sup>2</sup> you need, and the magic will furnish the manufacturing process including fermentation etc.

Clearly there are a lot of questions if you start thinking about the details of the process<sup>3</sup>, but this is magic, and D&D is [not a physics simulation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196846/is-there-a-citation-for-dd-is-not-a-physics-simulation), so we'll handwave them.

The challenging part is this sentence in the fabricate spell:

> You can fabricate a Large or smaller **object**

Object is a [defined game term](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95532/what-is-considered-an-object), and if liquids are objects [is debatable](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/197277/can-i-light-up-honey-or-other-non-solid-objects-with-the-light-cantrip). Your DM will need to decide that. If they decide they are, then you can manufacture beer with the spell.

---

<sup>1</sup> *If you do not consider yeast as an ingredient, but rather as "worker" doing the transformation, then you would not even need any to create beer, just hops, water, and grain.*

*If you consider yeast an ingredient, there is no issue with yeast being a simple life form. While fabricate says* Creatures (...) can't be (...) transmuted by this spell *, both the [definition of creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47254/what-is-the-definition-of-creature-and-is-it-used-consistently) is ambiguous enough to ingore simple life forms if convenient, and* trees *are listed as a raw material, by the spell, so it [specifically tells us](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135076/is-there-a-hierarchy-of-specificity) normal plants, which include fungi like yeast in the game, are OK.*

<sup>2</sup> *The listing of weapons, armor, and jewelry supports that you can craft things from multiple materials, as many of these are composed of multiple materials, for example a normal axe has a wooden handle and a metal head, plate armor has leather straps for fastening the plates, etc.*

<sup>3</sup> *For example, if you could only reshape raw materials, not transform them, you could not even create a dagger from an iron ingot: that requires a process of heating and tempering to toughen the metal. You frankly could not create much of anything.*

Answer (score -3):

## Yes, if the raw material is 'beer'

You can make older beer out of younger beer, since the latter is the raw material for the former and they are of the same substance.  You cannot make younger beer out of older beer, though, since the elder is not the raw material for the younger, nor can you make beer from hops, barley, wheat, water, etc since the finished product is not of the same substance as the ingredients.

Answer (score -4):

### Not a *genuine* beer, because brewing real beer involves a creature (yeast) which is outside the scope of the spell

Part of the *fabricate* spell description reads:

> Creatures or magic items can't be created or transmuted by this spell.

The yeast are tiny organisms that digest the malted barley and emit alcohol and CO2 as by-products, as they re-produce like mad. To magically cause (or accelerate) this function would be creating millions and millions of yeast organisms, which is precluded by the spell description.

For clarity: Even though the spell lets you make a bridge out of "trees", this treats the trees as merely a source of lumber, and no longer as living creatures for purposes of the construction. But in beer making, the yeast need to function very largely and significantly as creatures -- consuming, metabolizing, reproducing, etc.  So the creation or modification of living organisms is part and parcel of making the beer, completely unlike building a bridge out of lumber.  Non-pasteurized beer is generally "still alive" when you drink it, even.

Furthermore, the spell description also says (emphasis mine):

> You convert raw materials into products *of the same material*.

You asked about what could happen if you would bring together the ingredients of the beer.  But by the time beer is made, it is not longer "of the same material" as its "raw ingredients" were.  Ethyl alcohol and CO2 are not among the "raw materials" for making beer -- they emerge as the result of the organic transformation that occurs during brewing.

#### Can you just make beer without using yeast?

Again, not *real* beer. Because if you could make malted barley wort into alcohol somehow without using yeast, you'd be missing that the [yeast contributes some of the distinctive flavor](https://drinks.seriouseats.com/2013/01/how-to-indentify-yeast-character-in-beer-what-are-esters-phenols-alcohol.html) of beer (it's not just for producing alcohol).

#### Are yeast possibly not even "creatures" in 5e, and does it matter for this question?

It's not entirely clear. The RAW SRD says, in describing "plants" as a type of "creature":

> Fungal creatures such as the gas spore and the myconid also fall into this category.

And yeast are indeed [fungal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeast).

But wait, the RAW also says (of the"plants" type):

> Plants in this context are vegetable creatures, not ordinary flora.

Despite *that* statement, the *Awaken* spell is commonly understood to be able to target "ordinary flora" such as a common oak tree, even though it says the target has to be a "beast or plant". This seems to imply that when an initially ordinary plant is about to be the subject of the effects of a spell that transmutes it with magical effects, *then* it is treated as a creature.

Putting this all together, I suppose a DM could rule either way, as to whether yeast are "creatures" in this context, but even if they aren't, you need to facilitate a *vast multiplication of the starting amount of yeast* when you engage in beer making.  If you want to assert that *fabricate* could let you do that, then where does it stop? Why could it not also let you build a ten-ton wooden bridge from just ten pounds of wood?  So again it's hard to defend using fabricate to make *real* beer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation largely about yeast has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89418/discussion-on-answer-by-valley-lad-can-the-fabricate-spell-create-beer).

Comment: I don't think that either trees nor yeast are considered *creatures* from a RAW prespective.

Comment: @Masclins You might be right but I don't think the RAW is really clear here.  Adding a note to my answer about this.

Comment: living is not the same as creatures, the description of Plant type creatures specifically excludes normal flora. the spell awaken targets a beast or plant not  beast or plant type creatures. plant is not the same as Plant in dnd.

Comment: Building a bridge requires creatures (workers) yet most of the people can agree that fabricate wouldn't fail for that reason. Why are yeast different?

Comment: @Mołot The workers are not the *material* that you use to make the bridge, The spell uses magic to manipulate materials so that workers are not needed to do so; the workers are not part of the product itself, which the yeast most certainly is.

Comment: @ValleyLad No, you don't need yeast in finished beer. Most of the time you do what you can to avoid getting them in your beer as it ruins clarity. Commercial breweries now use microfiltration, historically clearing agents like egg whites or prepared fish bladders were used to get rid of as much yeast as possible from the solution. I bet I brewed more hectolitres of beer than you ;) so chances that you convince me I don't know how it's made are next to zero.

Comment: @Mołot Granted filtration removes yeast, but that is a modern convention and we are talking about D&D and thinking of medieval ales and lagers, I would presume. But even after filtration the yeast contributes materially to the flavor or taste of the finished beer, mainly from esters and phenols, though it depends on the strain of yeast how *much* of this effect is present and how strong the flavor contribution is, but it is always there. Filtration doesn't get everything out -- thank goodness, or else the fruity flavor of a typical Belgian ale just wouldn't be the same.  ;)

Answer (score -4):

## Unlikely, you can only using a single raw material source

*Fabricate* states

> You convert raw materials into products of the same material. For example, you can fabricate a wooden bridge from a clump of trees, a rope from a patch of hemp, and clothes from flax or wool.

In the examples given, you are always converting a single raw material into fabricated object using only that raw material.

If a DM is willing to stretch the spell to emulate complex manufacturing/creation, then that may be up to them - but the wording of the spell suggests the single raw material type limitation.

Comment: They also mention weapons and armor, which are made of both leather and metal. Jewelry combines a jewel and a metal setting. It could be argued that, because both of these are in the last passage which refers to more complex projects, you'd need proficiency to use more than one material however.

Comment: @miles-bedinger good point, but it's unclear if that overwrites the initial requirement and that it's the craftsmanship that requires the tools/knowledge. Definitely feels like a DM call.

Comment: Seems that the prototypical examples of *fabricate* all make a product *mainly* out of one type of raw material but w/supplemental elements: a bridge is mainly wood (but includes some nails or screws or rope); a rope is mainly hemp fibers (but can be waxed or dyed); armor is mainly metal or leather (but with connectors or lining), etc.

Comment: @ValleyLad: you could make a bridge without nails, using wooden pegs, dovetails etc. In fact, a lot of wooden furntiure was made that way in medieval times. Likewise, you could make cloths without dying them. The weapons, armor and jewelry however do provide good examples that requrie compound materials.